# which python package can be used for text to speech?

Tags: jquery, python, text-to-speech

The purpose for using text to speech is to make the bot speak what is there in the specific division of the html body.
can I use jquery to do the above tts? if yes, what is the package i should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use **Javascript**, I recommend you to use https://responsivevoice.org/.
It's easy to install and configure :

```html
<script src='https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js'></script>
<input onclick='responsiveVoice.speak("Hello World");' type='button' value=' Play' />
```